# Error Code: 1111 Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

Ребята как мне реализовать этот вариант :

```
    Select 
        t1.name
    from t1
    inner join t2
      on t2.t1_id = t1.id
    where count(distinct(t2.id)) = 5
   group by t1.id
```

Как я понял `count` в месте агрегатными функциями невозможно.

Как мне сделать выборку тогда ?

Comment: 1) Отсутствует выражение связывания (секция ON), это плохо. 2) Отсутствует секция GROUP BY - это фатально.

Comment: Ваш запрос вообще странно написан. Во первых, в `JOIN` не указано условие `ON` по какому полю(ям) таблицы должны быть соединены. Во вторых, отсечение записей по агрегатным функциям должно быть в предложении `HAVING` после `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже написали в комментариях, у вас две проблемы:

1. В `JOIN` не указано условие `ON` по какому полю(ям) таблицы должны быть соединены.
2. Отсечение записей по агрегатным функциям должно быть в предложении `HAVING`после `GROUP BY`.

Ваш запрос должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
SELECT 
    t1.name
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id -- тут условие по которым таблицы соединяются
GROUP BY t1.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(t2.id)) = 5
```

Comment: Отлично ,спасибо.А чо having после group by идет ?

Comment: @Sergey `HAVING` это `WHERE` для агрегатных функций — [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL))